# Confusion in number of turns and strands in flyback transformer

Tags: current, transformer, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, wire

I am designing my own discontinuous mode flyback transformer and am following the book [Transfomers and Inductors Design Handbook by Colonel. Wm. T. Mclyman](http://ebook.pldworld.com/_eBook/-Power%20Electronics-/TRANSFORMER%20and%20INDUCTOR%20DESIGN%20HANDBOOK%203rd%20Edition,%20Revised%20and%20Expanded/ourdev_725050HHOGA4.pdf). I have used all the equations of the discontinuous mode Isolated transformer but am getting a very strange result, which I don't know how to tackle it.

According to my requirements:
Vin=12V,Vout=100V,I out=0.6A freq=60kHz. The input peak current calculated is 23.2A. Irms=9.47A, wire chosen is 26 SWG, efficiency 0.95, Bm=1400G, Ku=0.29

Now according to the equations in the book, I calculated the energy and with the help of that, I was able to find out the number of strands. The energy I received is 0.0016 Ws. The core I have chosen is the ETD-39. According to the following equations, my number of strands(Snp) came out to be 32 in the primary. This is a very high number. My number of turns came out to be 6 then.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure how dividing the total current Area by the wire area gives me the number of strands. Shouldn't it give the total number of wires that appear in the window area for all the turns? Secondly, my turns came out to be 6 from that.

I wanted to ask if I can somehow choose a current density according to my current requirement of 9.47A rms instead of using this equation. This way I can choose the minimum strands with larger turns.

Kindly suggest to me What should be done in this case and also if the equation of the number of strands is valid or not.

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || All relevant improvements to the question decided during the chat, should be made via a question [edit], not as a comment. When someone has got enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Thanks.

Comment: *Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149680/discussion-on-question-by-kam1212-confusion-in-number-of-turns-and-strands-in-fl); please do not continue the discussion here.*